# I don't understand the type declarations

Tags: haskell, types

I struggle to understand how type declarations work...
Like these ones for example:

t :: (a -> b) -> (b -> c) -> a -> c

s :: (a -> b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c

I know from just trying different things that the correct functions would look like this:

```
t :: (a -> b) -> (b -> c) -> a -> c 
t f g x = g (f x)
```

```
s :: (a -> b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c 
s f g x = f x (g x)
```

But how does this work? Why are the brackets at the end? Why is it not

```
t f g x = (f x) g
```

or

```
s f g x = (f x) g x
```

Im so lost

Comment: To take `t` as an example, `f` has type `a -> b` while `x` has type `a`, so `f x` has type `b`. It makes sense to apply `g` (of type `b -> b`) to that, as in the correct definition `g (f x)`, but `(f x) g` (which can also be written `f x g`) makes no sense as `b` is not a function type in general so you can't apply it to `g`.

Comment: Thank you! But doesn't `g` have type `b -> c` ? @RobinZigmond

Comment: Make a concrete example: choose `a = b = c = Int` and let `f` be the `(+2)` function, `g` be the `(*10)` function, and `x` be 42. These choices respect the types. Now, `g (f x)` makes sense, it's `(42+2)*10`, but `(f x) g` is the same as `44 g` and that makes no sense since 44 is not a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first example:

```
t :: (a -> b) -> (b -> c) -> a -> c
```

In a type declaration, the `type1 -> type2` pattern indicates a function from `type1` to `type2`.  In type declarations, the `->` operator is right-associative, so this is parsed as:

```
t :: (a -> b) -> ((b -> c) -> (a -> c))
```

This kind of construction is called "currying":  providing the first argument (type `a -> b`) yields a function which accepts the second argument (type `b -> c`) which yields a function which accepts the third argument (type `a`).

The function declaration syntax is set up to do this automatically.  The first two arguments are functions and the third is just `a`, so start with names that reflect that:  `f :: a -> b` and `g :: b -> c` are functions, while `x :: a` is a fully generic type which could be anything.

```
t f g x = ...
```

Note that function application in Haskell is just concatenation:  to apply function `f` to value `x`, just use `f x`.  This syntax is *left*-associative, so `t f g x` is parsed as `(((t f) g) x)` to match the currying construction described above.

Anyway, given these types, you don't have much choice in how to put them together:

- the only thing you know about the type `a` is that it's the type of `x`, and the argument type of `f`, so the only thing you can do with them is to apply the function to the value: `f x`.
- the only thing you know about the type `b` is that it's the result type of `f` and the argument type of `g`, so the only thing you can do is apply `g (f x)`.
- the only thing you know about the type `c` is that it's the result type of `g` and of the overall function `t`, so the only thing `t` can return is `g (f x)`.

The reason you can't do `(f x) g` is that the types don't match:

```
f :: a -> b
x :: a
(f x) :: b

g :: b -> c
```

So, you can apply `g :: b -> c` to `(f x) :: b` to get a result of type `c`.  But not the other way around, because `b` might not even be a function type.